# GCP Looker Studio (Formerly DataStudio) - How to export and reimport a dashboard

Tags: google-cloud-platform, looker-studio

How to export and re-import a dashboard in Google Looker Studio (Formerly DataStudio). Any format will do; json/yaml/proprietary. I am looking for ways to not handcraft every lower environment dashboard panel in production as well.

I am not looking to export the data. I am only looking to export the dashboard and its panel definition. In other words , looking for this dashboard as a code

Comment: This functionality does not exist.

Comment: I was looking for the same things as Looker Studio IaC to reproduce dashboards in a controlled manner. Not that google would look at this soon, but does anyone know how to make a feature request for this?